# Use Javascript to show the difference between two cells in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, html-table

This must be fairy simple but I am still quite new to JS and can't find a solution. Let's assume I have this table:

```
<table class="mytable">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th>Price A</th>
         <th>Price B</th>
         <th>Up/Down Amount</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>23.5</td>
         <td>90.6</td>
         <td>Difference</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

1. How would I get JS to show the difference between priceA and PriceB and color it red or green depending on whether B is higher or lower?
2. If One of the numerical values is generated by a shortcode (wordpress) how do I get the JS to parse it? I have tried `$(window).on("load", function(){ ..` but it did not work on other tables I have tested*

   - [Fiddle of this table](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GAwrB/) (color cell based on value being lower than another cell) it works here but I could NOT get it to Function in Wordpress at all.

Any help is would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you want difference between <td>90.6 and <td>23.5

Comment: Your jsFiddle background coloring isn't very clear.  The last row of <td> elements has no color at all on it, yet 4000 is less than 4500, so shouldn't 4000 be colored with a `background-color` of red?  Also, do you want background color or the actual color of the text??

Comment: Yes, the difference between the two is what im trying to get; background color.

Comment: This is still not clear.  If the difference between A - B is a negative number, do you want red?  If it is a positive number do you want green?  Is this what you are saying?

Comment: Also, where do you want the background color to show?  In the difference `<td>` element?  If you said yes to all of these questions, than have a look at my answer, just updated that does exactly this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$(".mytable tr").not(":first").each(function() {
    var td1 = parseFloat($(this).children("td.pricea").text()),
        td2 = parseFloat($(this).children("td.priceb").text()),
        difference = (td1 - td2),
        absNum = Math.abs(difference),
        largerNum = td1 > td2 ? td1 : td2,
        percentage = ((absNum / largerNum) * 100).toFixed(2);

    if (difference < 0)
       $(this).children("td.out").text(percentage).addClass("green");
    else
        $(this).children("td.out").text(percentage).addClass("red");
});
```

CSS:

```
table td {padding: 5px;}
.green {
    background-color: #C8FDD3;
}
.red {
    background-color: #FDC8C8;
}

.pricea:before {
   content: "$";
}

.priceb:before {
   content: "$";
}
.out:after {
   content: "%";
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2DS5/20/)

To get the difference percentage of 2 numbers, you take the difference, divide it by larger number, and multiply by 100.

If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: This is perfect, just one thing, if there a way to show the difference without the - symbol? And how would this look if I targeted specific classes instead of td elements? I say this since the final table may have cells that do not enter into the equation, so its easier to target say <td class="pricea"> instead of nth child.

Comment: To target the `td` elements with class of `pricea` only change to this:  `children("td.pricea")` for both `td1` and `td2`, so than in that case you wouldn't need `.eq(x)` where `x` represents the `index` of the `td` element.

Comment: Updated answer and jsFiddle with `positive` differences using `Math.abs`

Comment: If you don't supply us with the class names of each td element, than we can't really help you with that part, and we are trying to provide actual working examples, not guessing on class names, which you may or may not have assigned to any `<td>` elements.

Comment: Thank you very much, here's what I got now [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2DS5/11/)  ONLY issue is that since its subtracting some results end up as negative numbers like -67, except that since this is an increase in value (thus green) I want it to show without the - sign. Having the value that shows a decrease from pricea to priceb with a  - sign instead would be ideal... Any ideas? Should I try to use a RegEx for this?

Comment: Why did you change to `.removeClass('red').addClass('red')`? and you did the same with the green class on the element.  Why?

Comment: EDITED: GOT IT! [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/Y2DS5/12/) Thank you! Now I just need to get wordpress to play nice...

Comment: One more issues, I got it all working, but for some reason when I put it in a different table (still with numbers up to 2 decimals), the result keep printing 10+ decimal places. What would be a good workaround here? Strangely it only happens in one of two tables on the same page, using the same sample numbers...

Comment: Add `.toFixed(2)` to `Math.abs(difference)`.  Once again, updated answer.

Comment: Works like a charm, I was concerned about adding $ to the numbers, but a simple .class:before  fixed that. One LAST thing, how could I turn the output to a percentage? I this the right way to do it?  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2DS5/19/)

Comment: Updated jsFiddle in answer and code in answer to that which is specific for you.  If this answers your question, please mark it as the answer.  Thanks :) and by the way, my answer is more Precise, because it doesn't convert it to 2 decimals until it is ready to be outputted, thus doing all calculations on the entire NUMBER, including decimals.

Comment: I have ran into a small fix I need for this script: How could I make the the percentages in red (when priceb is lower than pricea) output as negative numbers?

Comment: Ok, so `Math.abs` handles the removal of the negation on numbers.

Answer (score 0):

see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/GAwrB/160/)

```
$(".colorMe tr").each(function() {
    if (($(this).find("td:eq(0)").text()-$(this).find("td:eq(1)").text())>0)
    {
            $(this).css("background","red");

    }
    else{
    $(this).css("background","green");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

call this function on window.onload or any other event, check this demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAwrB/165/)

```
function cal()
{
 var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
 for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
 {
   var tds = ele[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

     var td1 = parseInt(tds[0].innerHTML);
     var td2 = parseInt(tds[1].innerHTML);
     tds[2].innerHTML = td2-td1;
     if(td1>td2)
     tds[0].style.backgroundColor = "green";
     else
     tds[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! OK, so I am playing around with this and its not quite there yet, I'm having trouble grasping the logic. Here's a simpler version of the fiddle using specific classes, but its not working anymore, what am I getting wrong here? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GAwrB/166/)

Comment: document.getElementById return single node not collection of nodes

Comment: The background color will always be green with this answer.

Comment: when you want to show red ? what i did is greater one will be green

Comment: Actually, OP isn't clear on this, and the jsFiddle isn't clear on this either, even tho OP says it works in jsFiddle, doesn't for me, cause if it did, than last row of `td` elements should make 4000 have a background color of red, but it doesn't.  So, I'm not entirely sure on when the red or green is supposed to come into play here either.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mytable").find("tr").each(function() {
        var price_a = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text());
        var price_b = parseFloat($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)").text());
        var diff = price_a - price_b;
        var $res = $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)");
        $res.text(diff);
        if (diff < 0) {
            $res.css("backgroundColor", "red");
        } else {
            $res.css("backgroundColor", "green");
        }
    });
});
```